# How to add an json object inside another json object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Existing Json data

```
{'list': {'KEY1': 'One'}}
```

Need to add

```
{'KEY2': 'Two'}
```

Result :

```
{'list': {'KEY1': 'One', 'KEY2': 'Two'}}
```

Any idea how to do it in `python`?

I'm tried append but it creates array in json object like this

```
{'list': [{'KEY1': 'One'}, {'KEY2': 'Two'}]}
```

Comment: `{'list': {'KEY1': 'One'}, {'KEY2': 'Two'}}` is invalid syntax. `{'list': [{'KEY1': 'One'}, {'KEY2': 'Two'}]}` is probably the closest to what you are looking for.

Comment: Or you want `{'list': {'KEY1': 'One', 'KEY2': 'Two'}}`?

Comment: Oops.., Modified. Yes exactly I wanted like this

Comment: @jignasha `{'list': {'KEY1': 'One', 'KEY2': 'Two'}}` is valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict.update`:

```
s = {'list': {'KEY1': 'One'}}
d = {'KEY2': 'Two'}
s['list'].update(d)
```

Output:

```
{'list': {'KEY1': 'One', 'KEY2': 'Two'}}
```

Or in Python3, you can use dictionary unpacking:

```
s = {'list': {'KEY1': 'One'}}
d = {'KEY2': 'Two'}
s = {'list':{**s['list'], **d}}
```

Output:

```
{'list': {'KEY1': 'One', 'KEY2': 'Two'}}
```